# I'm getting: Use of unresolved identifier 'randomBallNumber1'; did you mean 'randomBallNumber'?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[Image with comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nj4y.png)

I'm learning to code in swift and using Xcode 10 the comments in the code you can see in the picture are my assignments, but the below is stressing me out, not quite sure why I am getting the error.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Post code as text directly in your question.

Comment: Ok sorry I’ll bare that in mind for future. I’m new to Stack overflow also as well as coding. Pls be gentle with me 

Comment: Please [edit] this question. No need to wait for a future question.

Comment: While the code is shown in an image, I'll vote to close as Missing a [mcve]. The reason we need is that the Q&A are for future readers, not just for question authors. Please do update this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UIImage(named:) wants a string not an array as an input parameter.

This name should be the name inside the asset's file of the project.

You should use `ballArray[randomBallNumber1]`

Answer (score -1):

Guess what you need is.

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: ballArray[randomBallNumber]
```

Because `ballArray` is an array an images names and `randomBallNumber` is an index of current image. I'm not sure what you mean by `randomBallNumber1`. There is no such variable in your code and that's exactly what error says.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and helping. I’m learning slowly but surely.